# Parallel.For step size

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, parallel-extensions

Does anyone know if there's any overload that would allow me to specify a step size in a `Parallel.For` loop? Samples in either `C#` or `VB.Net` would be great.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Google for "enumerable.range step" and you should be able to come upon alternate implementations of Enumerable.Range that provide stepped ranges.  Then you can just do a

```
Parallel.ForEach(BetterEnumerable.SteppedRange(fromInclusive, toExclusive, step), ...)
```

If google isn't working, implementation should be something like this:

```
public static class BetterEnumerable {
    public static IEnumerable<int> SteppedRange(int fromInclusive, int toExclusive, int step) {
        for (var i = fromInclusive; i < toExclusive; i += step) {
            yield return i;
        }
    }
}
```

Alternately if "yield return" gives one the heebie jeebies, you can always just create a regular old list in-place:

```
var list = new List<int>();
for (int i = fromInclusive; i < toExclusive; i += step) {
    list.Add(i);
}
Parallel.ForEach(list, ...);
```

This should be easily translatable to VB if that's a requirement.

Comment: Thanks Dax. Would it be too much extra work if i'm trying to do this in VB.Net where there's no yield return?

Comment: No VB experience, but you should be able to use a for loop to make a List Of Integer with the integers you need, and then use `Parallel.ForEach` with that list.

Comment: @Gonzalo: The [async CTP](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=22388) enables the use of iterators in VB.NET.