# How to increment index on a particular value in Parallel.For?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

I want to increment an index on a particular value, for example 2:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i+=2)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

How do I do the same using the `Parallel` class, like:

```
Parallel.For(0, 10, i =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
    i += 2; //this a naïve assumption, it's not working
});
```

**Edit**

I would like the `Parallel` loop to run only 5 operations (as the sequential for) and order doesn't matter for me.

Comment: The increment in this case is also known as the *stride*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parallel.For step size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142446/parallel-for-step-size)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The implicit assumption in the first loop is that j is incremented sequentially.
In the second example the value of j can be any of 0 -> 9 in any of the loops.

You can achieve the same behaviour by the following:

```
Parallel.ForEach(Enumerable.Range(0, 5).Select(i => i*2), i =>
{
  Console.WriteLine(i);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

It appears like you want to iterate over the values 0 to 10, with an increment of 2. Why not implement it like the following:

```
Parallel.For(0, 5, i =>
{
    int value = i * 2;
    Console.WriteLine(value);
});
```

Comment: This is not what you describe. This yields values from 0 to 18 with an increment of 2.

Comment: @SaniHuttunen Hi Sani, good observation, forgot to change the upper bound of 10 to 5, corrected now :)

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to do the equivalent of step size, then this post may help:

[Parallel.For step size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142446/parallel-for-step-size)

If you just want to omit a certain value you'll just need to ignore it.

The Parallel.For won't run the items in order, so `i += 2` is meaningless.

Comment: +1. The last statement should be "The Parallel.For will probably not run the items in order" since there is a possibility it will.

Answer (score 2):

A simple adaptation:

```
Parallel.For(0, 5, i =>
{
    int j = i * 2;
    Console.WriteLine(j);
    // i += 2; //this a naïve assumption, it's not working
});
```

In other words, you can almost alays find a projection from the sequential `i` to the desired loopvalue (`j`). rbitrary sr

The other stake-holder here is the partitioner, you can't expect it to deal with arbitrary sequences.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach would be to use where clause:

```
Parallel.ForEach(Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Where(i => i % 2 == 0), i =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
});
```