# Can a Parallel For loop iterate by something other than 1

Tags: c#, .net, parallel.for

How would I convert this to a parallel for loop?

```
for(int i = 0; i < 500; i += 25) 
{
    //...
}
```

Would something like this be inefficient?

```
For(0, 500, i =>
{
    if (i % 25 == 0)
    {
        //...
    }
});
```

[image]

Comment: I found another thread that answers my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8330262/how-to-increment-index-on-a-particular-value-in-parallel-for

Comment: Common pattern is to use `Environment.ProcessorCount` to reduce amount of calls from O(element count, e.g. 1_000_000 items) to O(proc count, e.g. 16). See [here](https://github.com/goldshtn/simd-workshop/blob/b05ed58516055af59a4bc7a1d8f36a3199d17c22/MinMax.cs#L73)